# ZF2 Logging exceptions and sending Email notifications?

Tags: php, email, logging, zend-framework2

I have a business critical application there an exception should never occur. However you never now. Thus I should log every exception.

I set up a logger like:

```
'log' => array(
    'Log\App' => array(
        'writers' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'stream',
                'priority' => 1000,
                'options' => array(
                    'stream' => 'data/logs/application/app.log',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I was wondering wether it is possible to log every exception? How do I configure it?

And is it possible to have an email/smtp as an log writer?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure how to do this in ZF2, but `Monolog` has a really elegant solution for this:

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog

https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog#send-alerts-and-emails

> Send alerts and emails
>
> NativeMailerHandler: Sends emails using PHP's mail() function.

Comment: I'd rather prefer a solution with ZF2 own logging facility.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the ZF2 Exception Mailer Module to get email on every exception: 
[ZF2 Exception Mailer Module](https://github.com/25th-floor/zf2-exception-mailer-module)